# Error initializing SparkContext while run "./bin/spark-shell"

Tags: scala, akka, apache-spark-1.5

I am using `spark-1.5.2` with `scala-2.11.7`, after successfully build with `sbt/sbt assembly` when i run `./bin/spark-shell` i got below error.

```
16/02/10 19:20:22 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
    akka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.3.4] does not match the provided config version [2.3.11]
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:209)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:504)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1991)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1982)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:20)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:24)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Spark-shell starts successfully but `SparkContext` was not created.

Does any one know how to deal with Akka Jar version mismatch?

Comment: use maven-3.3 or later to build Spark.

Comment: Thank you @kostya it works.